# Smart user input processing in Console

Tags: c#, console

I have to:
1. Write an information to user.
2. Read the typed message.
3. If message is empty then close application.

It is very simple to just read the user input in following way and process it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()).Length > 0)
        {
            // process line here and return output to console

            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

But as I am a purist I want to omit all repeated statements (like "Console.WriteLine(message);" in this example). I have already tried the do{..}while(..) loop with no success (repeated Console.ReadLine() statements).

Do you have any smart idea how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true)
{
     Console.WriteLine(message);
     var line = Console.ReadLine();
     if (line == "") break;
     else DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Is it OK to use infinite loops and a break? I was taught that it's "undesirable coding".

Comment: IMO, it is OK since C# doesn't have any more suitable constructions for that. I would prefer `while (true)` than moving some to condition and hence duplicating it. I think this topic is pretty subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Create lazily evaluated `IEnumerable<string>` (let's say I can get this `IEnumerable` from method `ReadAllLines` in sample below) which will return lines read from Console. Then you can do something like this with LINQ:

```
var lines = ReadAllLines()
                .TakeWhile(line => line != "");
foreach (var line in lines) DoStuff();
```